# Event listener not working on dynamically added element

Tags: jquery, events, handler, onclicklistener

I'm adding, an h1 tag to my document when a submit button is pressed, using jQuery. I want to interact with this h1 tag at a later time (with mouse clicks), so I need to add an event handler to it. However, it does not seem to be registering the clicks.

I've seen this question asked on SO before and they all say use .on(), which I have, but still no luck. I'm not receiving any errors either so don't know where to begin.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fXVeW/) of a very simplified version of it all. Thanks.

```
$("h1").on("click", function(){
    alert("test");
    $("h1").css("color","red");
})
```

Comment: @dystroy was a bit quicker, but here's a working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/fXVeW/1/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this :

```
$(document.body).on("click", "h1", function(){
    alert("test");
    $("h1").css("color","red");
})
```

The jquery set must contain, when you call `on` on it, the elements that will contain the `h1`. You might replace `document.body` with any element in which you're sure the `h1` will be.

**Side note :**

Are you sure you don't want `$(this).css("color","red");` instead of `$("h1").css("color","red");` ? Using `$(this)` would change the color of the clicked `h1` and not all `h1`.

Comment: That doesn't appear in the documentation does it. I just re-read it. It talks about the number of listeners that get added using his method, but not saying it's wrong. Or am I reading this incorrectly. Shouldn't his method still work?

Comment: @Leeish No : what happens is that the receiver (which must be in the jquery set on which you call on) delegates the event by dynamically looking for elements verifying the selector given as argument (here "h1").

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $(this).css("color","red") - That's a good suggestion thanks.

Comment: @DenysSéguret , as you said that receiver dynamically looks for elements verifying the selection. Now in the fiddle h1 is appended in div which is already inside body. Why does jquery not understand that the dynamically added element is  present or why does jquery treat the dynamically added elements differently?

Comment: The problem isn't really that the element is dynamically added, but that it is added *after* the execution of `$("h1")`. So the result of the `$("h1")` call is a collection *without* this element.

Answer (score 1):

try this

***JS CODE***

```
$(document.body).on("click", "h1", function(){
    alert("test");
    $(this).css("color","red");
});
```

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fXVeW/2/)***