# On click the image is not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

```
<form id="upload_form" action="" method="post">
      <label for="file_input">Select Files to Upload:</label>
       <input id="file_input" type="file"  multiple>
</form>
</p>
<input id="add" type="submit" value="add to canvas" >
<div id="layers_list" class="layers_col" ></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var file_input = $('#file_input');
    var layers_list = $('#layers_list');

    file_input.on('change',onFilesSelected);
    function onFilesSelected(event){
        var files = event.target.files;
        for(var i= 0;i<files.length; i++){
            var img = $("<img/>").attr("src",URL.createObjectURL(files[i]));
            img.attr("title", files[i].name);
            var heading = $("<h3></h3>").text(files[i].name.substr(0,12));
            $("<li></li>").append(img).append(heading).appendTo(".layers_col");
        }
    }
   $("#layers_list li img").click(function(){
        $(this).data('select',true);     //add images on click
        console.log("clicked");              
    });
    $("#add").click(function(){
         var selectedImgs = [];
        $("#layers_list li img").each(function(){
           $(this).data("select")? selectedImgs.push(this.name):false; //choose //selected images
         });
         alert(selectedImgs.join(','));
    });
});
</script>
```

After dynamically creating the list of image tags, i am not able to select images or store them in the data array. how can make this to work?

Comment: This is asked many times every day. Does somebody has a link to a good question for closing ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event listener not working on dynamically added element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841344/event-listener-not-working-on-dynamically-added-element)

Comment: Feel free to let me know if my answer ever worked or not :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [**event delegation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically created elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '#layers_list li img', function(){
    $(this).data('select', true);     //add images on click
    console.log("clicked");              
});
```

Comment: Do we really need to delegate event from base node that is `document`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add any event for elements which are dynamically generated, you need to add/bind required event using `on` event .

eg.

```
$("#layers_list").on('click', "li img", function(){
//code goes here..
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$("#layers_list li img").click(function(){
```

to

```
$("#layers_list").on('click', "li img", function(){
```